# Yii loading jquery multiple times

Tags: jquery, yii, partial-views

I currently have a page which renders 6 partial views. The problem that I am now facing is that, because I need to set processOutput to TRUE, jquery is loaded multiple times.

I tried to resolve this by adding

```
    <?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = FALSE; ?>
    <?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = FALSE; ?>
```

To my partial view. The problem is, that by doing so, jquery doesn't load AT all.

Anyway to resolve this so it will only load once?

Comment: What happens if you disable script map completly and include your jQuery files in html head section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<?php $jquery = '/js/jquery.min.js'; ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = $jquery; ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = $jquery; ?>
```

With this approach, you can use the asset manager. Example:

```
<?php $jquery = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::app()->theme->basePath . '/assets/jquery-1.9.1.js'); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = $jquery; ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = $jquery; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include following ClientScript mapping in your config file under components array

```
'clientScript' => array(
        'scriptMap' => array(
            'jquery.js' => '/js/jquery.min.js', // set your path here
        ),
    ),
```

Also add following to your `<head>` section

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

And remove anyother manual jquery include in your views. You should be fine.