# Yiitab error while using CTabView in yii

Tags: yii

In the process of learning about CTabView in yii,

I got an error that is

> jQuery(...).yiitab is not a function.

Ctabview is not working for second Tab ..

What is the solution and how to overcome this error.

any help ...thanks in advance

Comment: SO users are no magicians, please provide at least some code to us =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511060/yii-loading-jquery-multiple-times

Comment: sorry I had done it ...but I have mentioned the problem clear above..dont you understand the question above..

Comment: anyway i got the answer.....as i am new to SO. I dnt know how to use it.I need suggestions not questions